# COleStreamFile::OpenStream replacement in C#

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, filestream, carchive

I have a code written in MFC for file reading and writing. I am rewriting it for C#.

My file consists of three parts, **Header** **Body** and **Footer**. Now in MFC code CArchive can write/read any of these parts. This is done by **COleStreamFile::OpenStream**. In this method we gave which part to read and this returns stream pointing to that location in the file. CArchive then uses stream and reads/writes to the file.

```
COleStreamFile stream;
//Stream is pointed to footer location.
stream.OpenStream(m_pStg, "Footer", nOpenFlags, pError);  // pStg is LPSTORAGE
CArchive ar(&stream, CArchive::load);
```

Now after this code when I do **ar >>** or **ar <<** I didn't read file from start. It is reading from middle or end (depends on stream). Now what I want is that to convert this code to C#. Whats the replacement for **COleStreamFile::OpenStream** in C#.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream)
    {
    }
}
```

Now here stream is pointing to the start. I think I can give it to read from specific byte. But I don't know that byte location. What I know is **Header**, **Body** and **Footer** names which are being used by MFC code.

Or is there any way to find out the current location of CArchive when it is reading or writing. If I get byte location from there I can use that as well.

Comment: I think you would be better off keeping your code in C++ and writing a wrapper for C#. Otherwise you'll need to figure out what `COleStreamFile` is doing to point to each part of the file and mirror it in C#.

Comment: Well we are getting rid of legacy code. And writing wrapper doesn't make sense in my case.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for COM structured storage. [Is there any library to access OLE Structured Storage from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897328/is-there-any-library-to-access-ole-structured-storage-from-c). [Nuget Package](https://nuget.org/packages/OpenMcdf/)